# Java Using CountDownLatch to poll a method until a success response

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, polling, countdownlatch

I am trying to call a method multiple times every 60 seconds until a success response from the method which actually calls a rest end point on a different service. As of now I am using do while loop and using

```
Thread.sleep(60000);
```

to make the main thread wait 60 seconds which I feel is not the ideal way due to concurrency issues.

I came across the CountDownLatch method using

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
boolean processingCompleteWithin60Second = latch.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

@Override
public void run(){

    String processStat = null;
    try {
        status = getStat(processStatId);
        if("SUCCEEDED".equals(processStat))
        {
            latch.countDown();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

I have the run method in a different class which implements runnable. Not able to get this working. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: why are you calling await twice? What do you mean be 'not able to get this working?'

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I have corrected it. The problem here I am facing is that, I am calling the method from the Runnable class and not able to figure out how to pass the success/error response from the runnable class to the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work using Executor Framework.

```
            final int[] value = new int[1];
            pollExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {

                Map<String, String> statMap = null;

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        statMap = coldService.doPoll(id);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                    if (statMap != null) {
                        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : statMap
                                .entrySet()) {
                            if ("failed".equals(entry.getValue())) {
                                value[0] = 2;

                                pollExecutor.shutdown();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            try {
                pollExecutor.awaitTermination(40, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `CompletableFuture` instead of `CountDownLatch` to return the result:

```
CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

invokeYourLogicInAnotherThread(future);

String result = future.get(); // this blocks
```

And in another thread (possibly in a loop):

```
@Override
public void run() {

    String processStat = null;
    try {
        status = getStat(processStatId);
        if("SUCCEEDED".equals(processStat))
        {
            future.complete(processStat);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        future.completeExceptionally(e);
    }   
}
```

`future.get()` will block until something is submitted via `complete()` method and return the submitted value, or it will throw the exception supplied via `completeExceptionally()` wrapped in an `ExecutionException`.

There is also `get()` version with timeout limit:

```
String result = future.get(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: The project is running on Java 7. Wont be able to make use of CompletableFuture.

Comment: Is using Guava an option? I mean its `ListenableFuture`: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html